# Error displaying rows from MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get rows from a table when a condition is satisfied (status = 'no transit') but nothing shows up even when rows are supposed to show up (count is 1 and more).

```
         if($query['num'] == 0){
            echo "<p>No shopping orders on transit</p>";
          }else{

              $sql = "SELECT *, FORMAT(total, 0) AS total, FORMAT(grand_total, 0) AS grand_total FROM shipping_details WHERE status = 'no transit' ORDER BY order_id DESC";

              foreach ($db->query($sql) AS $query){
              echo" Show some results ";

              $select = "SELECT * FROM shipping_order WHERE order_id = :order_id";

                foreach ($db->query($select, array('order_id' => $query['order_id'])) AS $items){

                echo"
                Some results
                ";
                //Foreach ends
              }
            }
         }
```

Comment: What is the mystery error that you say shows up?

Comment: What type of object is `$db`? In the inner query, you use the bound parameter `:order_id` with a `query()` method. If this is a normal PDO object, that would need to be done in `prepare()/execute()`, but if it is a custom wrapper class on PDO that implements a `query()` method accepting parameters, please post that class definition (or the relevant parts of it)

Comment: Always when developing and testing code, at the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. And if that is a PDO object as it appears to be, enable exceptions on it with `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Answer (score 0):

It is not working, because you forgot to use prepare and execute methods from pdoStatemnt class.

See below:

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM shipping_order WHERE order_id = :order_id");

 $stmt->execute(array('order_id' => $query['order_id']));

                while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                echo"
                Some results
                ";
                //Foreach ends
              }
```

Comment: This is not the problem. If I should tweak that query like say (name = 'john doe') instead of (status = 'no transit'), I get results. (status = 'no transit') does not seem to show any result even it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show enough that we can tell which codebase you use to connect to your DB (MySQLi, mysql_, or PDO), so the code below may need some tweaking.

The problem is basically that you never retrieve your database results. Instead you try to loop through the query execution itself.

Change

```
$sql = "SELECT *...";
foreach ($db->query($sql) AS $query)...
```

To

```
$sql = "SELECT *...";
$result = $db->query($sql); //execute the query
if(!$result) die($db->error); //exit and show error if query failed

//now we can fetch the results one at a time and loop through them
//this line may need to be adjusted if you're not using MySQLi
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())...
```

Within the `while` loop, `$row` will contain the values from the DB record.  Use `print_r($row)` to learn its shape.

Comment: note that if this is indeed PDO, `$db->query($sql)` is traversable and will work on a `foreach`, hard to answer with incomplete tags and information

Comment: @Ghost Interesting; did not know that.

Comment: If I should tweak that query like say (name = 'john doe') instead of (status = 'no transit'), I get results. (status = 'no transit') does not seem to show any result even it is supposed to.